# How To Set Equal Margins for Entire Web Page

Tags: css, margins

This question may have been beaten to death, but after looking through posts and Googling the heck out of it, I cannot find a functional code to get this to work and nothing I tried is doing the trick.

I'd like to set ALL (top, left, bottom, and right) page margins to 1%, but nothing I'm doing works. The only way I can get this to work is to manually size my images using height and width properties, which I'd like to avoid.

Ideally I'd like something like this:

```
body, html {
margin-left:1%;
margin-right:1%;
margin-bottom:1%;
margin-top:1%;
}
```

But that doesn't work. Any clean, straightforward suggestions on accomplishing this out there?

Comment: So, what's the problem with the above code? What seems to be going wrong?

Comment: @scooterlord using that code only sets margins to the top and left margins. The bottom and right margins are not present.

Comment: @DanielRippstein - please see my revised JS Fiddle. I'm trying to obtain 4 equal-sized divs. I went off the code that you provided, but what I added is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/0ayu7f2c/3/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? In the future, please describe the desired result fully in your question... for example, you never said you wanted 4 equal-sized divs, one in each corner of the screen, in your original question. But no worries, I've updated my answer below with some suggestions and I hope they solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary

Your margins are working correct. However, page margins do not apply to `position:fixed` elements.

### Details

This is not a glitch, but is by design according to [the W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning). Putting a left/right/top/bottom on a fixed element will move it relative to **the viewport** (your window). It won't even check for margins on `<body>` or any other parent element. After all, position:fixed is designed so that an element stays fixed to a part of window, even when scrolling... it needs to be fully independent of other elements to behave this way.

**So why did changing the 'top' and 'left' padding/margin of `body` seemed to work?**

Because position:fixed is calculated in basically two steps:

1. Lock the element at its starting position, as if it was position:static.
2. If a left/right/top/bottom is found, apply
   that change, but leave everything else positioned the way it
   started.

So here's what happens on your example:

1. If your `<div>`s were position:static, they would start in the
   top-left corner, but be pushed down 1% and left 1% because of that
   `<body>`'s margin/padding.
2. You don't set any left/right/top/bottom on the 1st `<div>`, so it
   stays in place permanently.
3. The 2nd `<div>` has a `right: 0` on it though; and as it doesn't
   *really* care about anybody's margin/padding, it goes straight to the right edge of the window like it was born to do.

Basically, the `<body>` gets to indirectly affect the `<div>`s, but setting a `right: 0;` blows that all away.

### Solution

Don't worry about putting padding/margin on the `<body>`, getting hard-to-predict results. Instead, apply CSS directly to the fixed elements. For example:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
div.nw {
    height:50%;
    width:50%;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color:#ff0;
    padding: 1% 0 0 1%;
}
div.ne {
  height:50%;
  width: 50%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 1% 1% 0 0;
  background-color:blue;
  position:fixed;
}
```

See it in action here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/isDhA

**EDIT:**

If you don't want the background color near the edges either, just combine the above technique with some simple inner divs. Such as in this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lDebh

**EDIT 2:**

After further discussion in the comments, here's some other suggestions, depending on what you need.

***"I want to have equal-sized divs in each corner of the window. It should be fixed to the background, so it doesn't scroll with everything else"***

Use this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/fettj66r/9/

```
.corner {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.nw {
    background: red;
    left: 1%;
    top: 1%;
}
.ne {
    background: green;
    right: 1%;
    top: 1%;
}
.sw {
    background: blue;
    left: 1%;
    bottom: 1%;
}
.se {
    background: black;
    right: 1%;
    bottom: 1%;
}
```

***"I want to have equal-sized divs in each corner of the window. It should scroll with everything else."***

Use this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/fettj66r/10/

```
body {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1%;
}
.corner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.nw {
    background: red;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.ne {
    background: green;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.sw {
    background: blue;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.se {
    background: black;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

If you have any questions about the above techniques, or this isn't what you needed either, feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: this doesn't create the margins for the body as OP asked

Comment: This is not the _technique_ he asked for, but it is the _end result_ he wanted. If he wants the margin technique, he can mark one of the other answers as accepted. However, he's using position:fixed (something that all the other answers quietly ignored and removed). My suggestion positions his fixed divs 1% away from the body edge, like he wanted. This is the end result he asked for. But there's no way body margins are capable of producing this result. Either he stops using position:fixed (like in the other answers), or he uses a different technique like I'm suggesting.

Comment: did you take a look at his comment on his question? "@DanielRippstein - please see my revised JS Fiddle. I'm trying to obtain 4 equal-sized divs. I went off the code that you provided, but what I added is not working: jsfiddle.net/0ayu7f2c/3 " - on this fiddle he is not using position:fixed . ;)

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ayu7f2c/5/)

```
body, html {
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    margin-bottom:1%;
    margin-top:1%;
    width:98%;
    height:98%;
}
```

for setting height margin you have to set height